# 質問の表示を元のスタイルに戻すには

Tags: サポート, 完了

現在の90年スタイルのデザインから元のデザインに戻したいと考えていますが、
表示されるポップアップには下記のようにあります。

> **Back to the future!** 
>   Just like the '90s, good things have to come to an end.
>   If you want to switch to the current site, you'll find the option here.

「現在のサイトに戻す場合は、ここにオプションがあります。」とありますが、
"設定"などを覗いても見つけることが出来ません。
ポップアップ自体にもリンクは無いようですので、オプションの場所をつかみかねています。
どうやったら、現在のサイトに戻せますでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

以下いずれかの方法で本来の表示に戻すことができるはずです。

1. ヘッダのポップアップメニューが指している時計のアイコン部分をクリックする
   (再度クリックすることで90年代スタイルとの表示が切り替えできます)
   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
2. 画面左側にある「Go to the future」のボタンをクリックする
   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます。理解しました。そもそもアイコンが増えていたことに気づいていませんでしたが、ポップアップがユーザアイコンに合っていたので、てっきりユーザ設定内にあるものと思っていました。